# Fastest way to check if a item is in a list - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, python-3.x

I'm having a problem making a vocabulary of words in python. My code goes through every word in a document of about 2.3MB and checks whether or not the word is in the dictionary, if it is not, it appends to the list

The problem is, it is taking way to long (I havent even gotten it to finish yet). How can I solve this?

Code:

```
words = [("_", "hello"), ("hello", "world"), ("world", "."), (".", "_")] # List of a ton of tuples of words
vocab = []
for w in words:
    if not w in vocab:
        vocab.append(w)
```

Comment: How many words you got there? Any why not use `set()` instead of list?

Comment: can you provide a copy of the words you are checking against.

Comment: words is actually a list of tuples (n-grams)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you need `vocab` to have a particular order, you can just do:

```
vocab = set(words)
```

Comment: but what if a word appears more than once is the words list. I dont want any duplicates in my vocabulary. @AlexHall

Comment: @N.Chalifour yup, sets don't have duplicates.

Comment: thanks! it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

The following is a test to compare the execution time of for loop and `set()`:

```
import random
import time
import string


words = [''.join(random.sample(string.letters, 5)) for i in range(1000)]*10  # *10 to make duplicates!

vocab1 = []

t1 = time.time()
for w in words:
    if w not in vocab1:
        vocab1.append(w)
t2 = time.time()

t3 = time.time()
vocab2 = set(words)
t4 = time.time()

print t2 - t1
print t4 - t3
```

**Output:**

```
0.0880000591278  # Using for loop
0.000999927520752  # Using set()
```